# jQuery .click(function(){ not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
<a class="click_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_on">Show</a>
<div class="div_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_show">div content</div>
```

```
$('.div_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_show').hide();   
$('.click_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_on').click(function(){ 
  $('.div_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_show')
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .show('slow') 
});
```

I trying to show dynamically a div content via JavaScript. But not working.

Comment: what are the values of `module_row ` and `element `

Comment: you code in fine you should check you `console` for `errors`

Comment: class cannot be like his . You can add the class name using jquery

Comment: The posted html doesn't make sense!

Comment: This method of programming can be overly complicated to debug because, only you know the variable values, what if they are empty or there is whitespace character

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024897/jquery-select-val-not-working ... really?

Comment: Nothing error in `console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are adding it dynamically via JavaScript, if that is the case you should use:

```
$(document).on('click','.click_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_on',function () {        
    // hide here, that is simple
});
```

Edit 1) DO you have module_row and element defined? I'm thinking that is the problem. Tell us more about those selectors?

Edit 2) Since you told me that module_row and elements are numbers, you should use different syntax. Use php to put module_row and element in attribute. Code HTML:

```
<a class="div_show" data-module="module_row" data-element="element">div content</div>
```

Code JS:

```
$(document).on('click','.click_on',function (e) {        
    // not to reload the page        
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var module = $(this).attr('data-module');
    var element = $(this).attr('data-element');
    $('div_' + module + '_' + element + '_show').hide()
});
```

You might need to tweak it around little more, but thats it

Comment: Check 2 things, html in inspect element just to see how selector would look like. Second thing put console.log('work'); just to see if you have an event.

My guess is that you dont have those variables defined globaly so you cannot have proper selection. Why do you put module_row and element? I think that there is more elegant solution than that

Comment: I working on php and this are example of a form which i create on php.

Comment: Yes  `' + module_row + '_' + element + ' = 1_2`

Comment: Thank you. Awesome .I make a sense from your code : I just modify some code `<a class="click_on"  titel="' + module_row + '_' + element + '">Show</a>   <div class="div_' + module_row + '_' + element + '_show">div content</div>`  and  `$(document).on('click','.click_on',function (e) {        
           e.preventDefault(e);
  var elements = $(this).attr('title');
    $('.div_' + elements + '_show').fadeOut('slow').hide('slow');
});`  is it right code? but now working for me.You saved me.Thanks...